# How to enter value into a text field which has no id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is relevant code

```
<input class="text last-name" type="text" value=""      name="hotelInformation.rooms[0].contactPerson.name.lastName">
```

I can not edit the HTML code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a `name` attr , you can use that to add a value to textbox
This reflects the exact text box unless until `hotelInformation.rooms[0].contactPerson.name.lastName` this name is unique

```
$('[name="hotelInformation.rooms[0].contactPerson.name.lastName"]').val("hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

use class selector then..

```
 $('.last-name').val('lastname');
```

if you are sure there is no other element with a class last-name.

else to be more specific, you can use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add text by class name if no id is present as:

```
$('.last-name').val('your text');
```

Or by:

```
$('input.last-name').attr('value', 'your text');
```

or by:

```
$( "input[name='hotelInformation.rooms[0].contactPerson.name.lastName']" ).val("your text");
```